# jQGrid set column width

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I found the way how to set jQGrid width:

```
$('#Grid1').setGridWidth(705, true);
```

It is resizing all columns according with this width when i am passing `true`. That is fine but the question is:  `Is it possible to keep constant width at least one column of grid when i call setGridWidth() or is it possible to change width only one column of the grid?`

In source code of grid there is a function `setColWidth = function () { }` but i not sure how to call this one and how to pass width as a prarm there, it is not accepting any params by the way.

Need help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using the [`fixed`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) colModel option to keep the width of one of the columns constant.

Comment: I was already to start implementing something like that http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RecreateGrid.htm but 'fixed' really helped!

Comment: any thoughts about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765741/jqgrid-reload-grid-after-save-inline-button-click ?